# Importing test classes into Scala console in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I am building a Scala project in the standard directory layout using sbt. I want to run `sbt console` and import my unit tests so that I can play with them in the Scala REPL. What is the easiest way to do this? Is there a command I can pass to sbt, or something I can add to `build.sbt`?

Note that I don't necessarily want to run unit tests from the `sbt console`. (Though that would be nice too.) Instead a have test fixtures that set up data structures that I want to use in my REPL session.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `test` configuration scope, like this:

```
sbt> Test/console
```

For more information, see [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html) in the sbt documentation.

With specs2 for example, you can go:

```
sbt> Test/console

console> import mytestpackage._
console> import org.specs2._
console> specs2.run(new MySpec)
```

Comment: My problem is that the `import mytestpackage._` fails because sbt doesn't know to look under `src/test` for packages to load.

Comment: Even with test:console instead of just console?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention. With `test:console` things do work. The answer to my questions is use `test:console`.