# How to load Test configuration jars in sbt console

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I am trying to write scalatest in the *sbt console* (REPL). But sbt console does not load dependencies marked as *Test configuration*.

```
sbt console
scala> <console>:12: error: object scalatest is not a member of package org
   import org.scalatest._
              ^
Interpreter encountered errors during initialization!

$ sbt
sbt:scalatest-example> consoleProject

scala> (fullClasspath in Compile).eval.files foreach println
/home/ashok/scala/anagram/target/scala-2.12/classes
/home/ashok/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.8.jar

scala> (fullClasspath in Test).eval.files foreach println
/home/ashok/scala/anagram/target/scala-2.12/test-classes
/home/ashok/scala/anagram/target/scala-2.12/classes
/home/ashok/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.8.jar
/home/ashok/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar
/home/ashok/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/bundles/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar
/home/ashok/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.8.jar
/home/ashok/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar
```

The workaround I have found is to remove the Test tag from scalatest. But this is not ideal. I would like to know if there is a more clean way, to load the Test configuration in console.

```
// libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031333/importing-test-classes-into-scala-console-in-sbt. Try `sbt "test:console"`

Comment: thanks Alexey. It works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing test classes into Scala console in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031333/importing-test-classes-into-scala-console-in-sbt)

Answer (score -1):

How about the double quoting the test part?

`libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.17" % "test"`